# Can I add properties to a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, function, object

If I do something like this it seems to work:

```
function a() { ... }
a.desc = "Description of a";
```

But can I break anything by doing that? Is there a better way?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why do you need a function instead of just declaring an object?

Comment: @webnoob Key bindings, descriptions for users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions):

> In JavaScript, functions are first-class objects, because they can have properties and methods just like any other object. What distinguishes them from other objects is that functions can be called. In brief, they are Function objects.

Since functions are first-class objects, there is no way of breaking down anything by adding properties to them.

Comment: Thanks, yes I know. But are there any restrictions of some kind?

Comment: What about property name clashes? If "desc" becomes a standard property name what will happen? How do I check for it?

Comment: I just added a check for `(function(){}).desc`.